# Обращение к элементам вложенного массива

Tags: php

Появилась задача интерпретировать конфиг вида

```
$need_fields = ['column1', 'column2.sub_column1', 'column2.sub_column2.sub_sub_column1']
```

Самое изящное решение, которое на ум пришло только преобразовать исходный массив из многомерного в одномерный с прописанными путями в ключе. Но рекурсивная функция, которая ничего не возвращает вероятно не очень красиво. Да и вероятно есть какая-нибудь функция стандартная, которая может воплотить мои желания.

```
function toOneArray($array, $prefix_key ="", &$result) {

foreach($array as $key => $value) 
{
    if(is_array($value))
       {
           toOneArray($value, $prefix_key.'.'.$key, $result);
           continue;
       }
       $result[$prefix_key.'.'.$key] = $value;
}

}
$result = [];
toOneArray($arr, '', $result);
           var_dump($result);
```

Comment: В Laravel есть всякие мазохистские [функции](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php#L109)

Comment: что конкретно вы хотите получить из этого массива?

Comment: @teran Конкретно хочу получить значения по конфигу $need_fields. Да, функция из Laravel выглядет по лучше, но идея та же. Спасибо.